# Understanding an example from Hatcher - cellular homology

Tags: algebraic-topology

Example 2.34: An Acyclic Space says the following - Let $X$ be obtained from $S^1 \vee S^1$ by attaching two 2-cells by the words $a^5b^{-3}$ and $b^3(ab)^{-2}$. Then $d_2: \mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2$ has matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 5 & -2\\ -3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, with the two columns coming from abelianizing $a^5b^{-3}$ and $b^3(ab)^{-2}$ to $5a - 3b$ and $-a + b$.

Now, $d_2$ here is the boundary map in the cellular complex, but don't understand why he claims that $d_2$ is determined this way. I realise that it must have something to do with the Hurewicz homomorphism, but I don't get how. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differential in cellular homology is determined by certain degrees of maps between spheres. Suppose $c$ is an $n$-cell in a CW complex $X$, with attaching map $$\alpha_c:\partial D^n\to X_ {n-1}\,.$$ For every (open) $(n-1)$-cell $d$, you can collapse its complement (in $X_{n-1}$) to a point; the quotient space is an $n-1$ sphere. This gives a projection
$$\pi_d:X_{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$$
(the right hand side isn't technically $S^{n-1}$, but can be canonically identified with a sphere, using the cell inclusion $d:D^{n-1}\to X_ {n-1}$). Then $\pi_d\circ\alpha_c$ is a map $S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$, both spheres have a preferred orientation, so that this map has a well defined degree, and by definition, the differential is defined on $c$ as
$$\partial c=\sum_{(n-1)\text{-cells }d}\deg(\pi_d\circ\alpha_c)\,d$$
This sum is always finite because $\alpha_c$ only meets finitely many $(n-1)$-cells in $X_{n-1}$.

---

So for instance, write $c$ for the $2$-cell you attached according to the attaching map $\alpha_c:S^1\to S^1\vee S^1$ that does $a^5b^{-3}$. If you collapse the complement of $a$ to a point, you get a map from the circle to itself that winds five times around, while if you collapse the first circle to a point, you get a map that travels three times around (in clockwise direction), and 
$$\partial c=5a-3b$$
if you call the second $2$-cell $d$, then it is attached via the map $S^1\to S^1\vee S^1$ via the map that does $b\cdot b\cdot a^{-1}\cdot b^{-1}\cdot a^{-1}$. It circles once around the second circle ($b$) and twice (clockwise) around the first direction, so that
$$\partial d=-2 a+b$$

Comment: Ok, but how does attaching by the above mentioned words give us the degree? And why does Hatcher mention abelianization?