# Homomorphism of $\langle a,b \mid a^5b^{-3}, b^3(ab)^{-2} \rangle$ and $A_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to prove that the map from $\langle a,b \mid a^5b^{-3}, b^3(ab)^{-2} \rangle$ to the alternating group $A_5$ defined by $a \rightarrow (12453)$ and $ b \rightarrow (234)$ is a homomorphism. I don't really know how I am supposed to go about this, having just started studying group theory. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Any relation to this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190045/understanding-an-example-from-hatcher-cellular-homology/1190085#1190085 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a group has presentation $\langle X|R\rangle$ then any map $X\to G$ extends to a homomorphism if (and only if) the images of the map satisfy the same relations as they do in the domain. So it suffices to check that the permutations (12453) and (243) satisfy the two given relations.

Comment: But I am getting $(12453)^5=(12453)$ and $(234)^{-3}=(432)^3=(432)$ and the composition $(12453) \circ (432) = (41253)$, so the first relation is not satisfied. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Every $k$-cycle has order $k$; you should be getting the identity for both $(12453)^5$ and $(234)^{-3}$. Your composition looks good, though.